# Visual Basic: How to delete specific column while looping through DataTable rows?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I'm looping through the datatable as follows:

```
For Each row As DataRow In records.Rows
    If row.Item("SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION") = "I" Then

    End If
Next
```

When the row meets the condition of the column, I need to remove an specific column of that same row.

I know how to do it, if I want to remove a column from the whole DataTable. Code is a simple as:

```
myDataTable.Columns.Remove("IdKey")
```

Simple code, yet, I don't find an answer around Google nor SO that explain how to remove a column withing the loop of rows.

Help! Thank you!

Comment: You cannot remove the column for just some rows. You can only set the cell to be empty.

Comment: Hmm, that's bad news. How can I set the cell to be empty then?

Answer (score 0):

Set cells empty:

```
Dim x = dt.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Where(Function(r) r("SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION") = "I")
x.ToList().ForEach(Sub(r) r("SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION") = Nothing)
```